# Index mapping in XSLT-2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have created index page using XSLT code. The contents name are shown to index page correctly but i want to map contents according to page number for specific title.

I am getting title with their description So I have named that block as id="TOC" and given as ref-id=”TOC” but the page number is not reflecting in my title.

Title:- Title names present in Index page.

Summary:- Title content associated with page.

The below is my XSLT-2.0 sample code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">        
    <xsl:template match="content_name">
        <fo:block space-after="7pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" language="FR">
            <fo:inline>
                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="TOC"/>
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pro_list">
        <fo:block space-after="15pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" language="FR">
            <fo:inline>
                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />
                <xsl:value-of select="title" id="TOC"/>
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>

        <fo:block space-after="8pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" language="FR">
            <fo:inline>
                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="summary" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output:

```
Contents
Title1                     page no.
Title2                     page no.
Title3                     page no.
```

Suppose title1 content is associated with page2 & similar for title2-3 & title3-4, then output looks like as follows

```
Contents
Title1                     2
Tilte2                     3
Title3                     4
```

Is there any syntax or predefined function available to do index mapping?

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to put the `id="TOC"` on the `xsl:value-of` or any `xsl` element, you need to give the id to a `fo` element.

Comment: I have tried to use id in FO block element.
<fo:block id="TOC" space-after="12pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.147" font-family="Calibri" font-size="15pt" font-weight="bold" text-decoration="underline" language="FR">
</fo:block>
It shows error :"Property ID "TOC" (found on "fo:block") previously used; ID values must be unique within a document! (See fo:block, id=TOC) (1 attempt) ".
This is autogenerated id=IDACAZEC" when i am using this id it gives the total page count.
Could you please give a small example how to give id in foo block.

Comment: Basically as far as I understand it using a generated id for an input element that is generated twice, once to generate content and once to generate a table of contents or an index, is the idea behind that. I have put up a minimal example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyP, you will need to edit your question and show us some more details of your XML input structure and the desired output plus the XSLT you have if that doesn't help.

Comment: As mentioned by you,tried that but doesn't works for me.Here the values are dynamic contents and summary.Will using this<fo:page-number-citation ref-id="{generate-id(.)}" /> generates the page reference number beside the content?

Comment: You will need to edit your question and show us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, XSL-FO you get and the one you want, to allow us to reproduce the problem, together with an explanation of what "doesn't work" exactly mean, e.g. if you get an error, if so which one exactly, by which tool exactly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.The input to XSLT is in JSON of array format & then translated it to XSLT sheet & tried code specified by you in last post. But we cant see any changes in the content page. Could you please help me, how can i sent input code since comment box is having character limitation.

Comment: Please edit your question, that way you can insert and add any code samples directly in the question. There is a link named "edit" below your question text to do that.